# using webpack in npm scripts section to transcompile es6

Tags: javascript, webpack, babeljs

using browserify, i can transcompile es6 to es5 by adding this to package.json -> scripts.

How do i do it using webpack and npm script?

```
"build-modular": "browserify index.js -t babelify -o index-bundle.js"
```

Answer (score 0):

In webpack instead of transforms you use loaders. Usually you configure loaders in a webpack configuration file. However, you can also [bind loaders in the command line](https://webpack.github.io/docs/using-loaders.html#cli).

As you want to *babelify* your `index.js` file, you need to install the corresponding [babel-loader](https://github.com/babel/babel-loader) and the required babel packages:

```
npm install --save-dev webpack babel-core babel-loader babel-preset-es2015
```

Now you are able to create your build script entry like this:

```
"build-modular": "webpack index.js index-bundle.js  --module-bind 'js=babel?presets[]=es2015'"
```

And run it:

```
npm run build-modular
```